# How do I fix Cygwin crashes inside X2Go client?

Tags: windows, cygwin, x2go

I am trying to connect to an Ubuntu x2go server, but I get:

[image: screenshot of X2go failure]

The message says:

```
NXPROXY - Version 3.5.0

Copyright (C) 2001, 2010 NoMachine.
See http://www.nomachine.com/ for more information.

Info: Proxy running in client mode with pid '13864'.
Session: Starting session at 'Tue Nov 24 23:29:06 2020'.
Info: Connecting to remote host 'localhost:43246'.
Info: Connection to remote proxy 'localhost:43246' established.
Info: Connection with remote proxy completed.
Warning: Unrecognized session type 'unix-kde-depth_32'. Assuming agent session.
      1 [main] nxproxy (2716) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2C87408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
      1 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 2716 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (14120) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2BA7408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
1128023 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 14120 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (9444) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2BE7408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
2265449 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 9444 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (2480) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2B87408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
3399581 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 2480 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (12244) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2C07408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
4530781 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 12244 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (13996) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2C47408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
5678374 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 13996 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (9752) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2C17408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
6865777 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 9752 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (5624) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2C67408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
8011632 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 5624 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      2 [main] nxproxy (9880) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2927408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
9140358 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 9880 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (9852) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2C27408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
10275915 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 9852 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (2672) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2C17408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
11410098 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 2672 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (6972) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2BC7408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
12544321 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 6972 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (15264) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2C07408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
13684065 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 15264 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (5764) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x29D7408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
14822751 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 5764 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (6308) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2BA7408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
15991748 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 6308 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (10612) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2CF7408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
17163726 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 10612 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (3600) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2BD7408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
18309047 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 3600 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (13964) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2B97408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
19440076 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 13964 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (14736) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x29A7408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
20574242 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 14736 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (11288) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2B37408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
21765507 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 11288 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (6104) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2C57408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
22973855 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 6104 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (3556) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2C17408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
24140838 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 3556 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (9928) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2DC7408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
25305901 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 9928 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (4452) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2A27408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
26478510 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 4452 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (14404) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2937408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
27630832 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 14404 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (420) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2B77408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
28785059 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 420 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
Connection timeout, aborting     60 [main] nxproxy (14180) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2BC7408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
29943676 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 14180 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
    366 [main] nxproxy (8296) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2B37408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
31108394 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 8296 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (4328) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2B77408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
32249460 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 4328 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
      1 [main] nxproxy (4856) C:\Program Files (x86)\x2goclient\nxproxy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x2D47408/0x2927408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
33429238 [main] nxproxy 13864 fork: child -1 - forked process 4856 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
Error: Function fork failed. Error is 11 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
Error: Failed to execute the X auth command.
Error: Cannot read the cookie from the X authorization file.
Error: Error creating the X authorization.
Session: Session terminated at 'Tue Nov 24 23:29:39 2020'.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've managed to solve it for now by:

1. adding x2go client to the PATH:
   [image]
2. restarting Windows

I don't know why restart helps, but I remember that it was part of advice for this error somewhere on the net. Also I remember setting some parameters for NXAGENT.EXE previously, may be this is part of a solution, unfortunately I can't recall which ones.